# Where and how to inject $stateParams?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, state, single-page-application

I am trying to get an image and a text into the view "home" in a Single Page Application with Angular `ui-router` and `$stateParams`.

```
'use strict';
angular.module('confusionApp')
.controller('IndexController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'menuFactory', 'corporateFactory', function($scope, $stateParams, menuFactory, corporateFactory) {

        var dish = menuFactory.getDish(parseInt($stateParams.id,10));
        $scope.dish = dish;

        var promo = menuFactory.getPromotion(parseInt($stateParams.id,10));
        $scope.promo = promo;

        $scope.leader = corporateFactory.getLeader($stateParams.abbr)

    }])

    .controller('AboutController', ['$scope', 'corporateFactory', function($scope, corporateFactory) {
        $scope.leaders = corporateFactory.getLeaders();

   }])
```

The menuFactory service works fine in a 'MenuController' both with a list  and with a parameter (injection while 'submit'). The corporateFactory works fine in a list using the 'AboutController'. But I just can't find out how to inject the $stateParam while index.html opens with the view 'home.html.

```
   <div class="container" ng-controller="IndexController">
    <div class="row row-content">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-sm-push-9">
            <p style="padding:20px;"></p>
            <h3 align=center>Our Lipsmacking Culinary Creations</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-sm-pull-3">
            <h4>Implement the Featured Dish Here</h4>
            <div class="media">
                <div class="media-left media-middle">
                    <a>
                        <img class="media-object img-thumbnail"
                        ng-src={{dish.image}} alt={{dish.name}}>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="media-body">
                <h2 class="media-heading">{{dish.name}}
                    <span class="label label-danger">{{dish.label}}</span>
                    <span class="badge">{{dish.price | currency}}</span></h2>
                <p>{{dish.description}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Would anybody help me, please?

Comment: index.html shouldn't contain the home view. It should contain the <ui-view> directive, and the router will inject the home view inside it if the URL is the URL of the home.

Comment: Sorry for describing it incorrectly. index.html contains 3 ui-view directives for header, content and footer. What I wanted to express is that when index.html loads,  home.html is loaded in the content region of index.html but without the '$stateParam' 'dish._id' specified. So '{{dish.image}}' etc. don't show.

Comment: Then remove `ng-controller="IndexController"` from the home view. But I don't understand what you're asking. What is the problem you're facing? You **are** injecting $stateParams.

Comment: Thanks, the controller is attributed in app.js  '.config' already, so I removed it. I've first heard about SPA a week ago and am still struggling. The view should show the dish with the index 0, one of 5 dishes defined in services.js. But instead of the image, I see the text for the expression {{dish.image}} in the rendered page.

Comment: That means you have an error. Open your browser console, leave it opened at all times while developing: it contains the error messsages.

Comment: I had an error in services.js that I corrected. Now I have a clean designer console - no errors - but still no objects show. I have to somehow indicate to the page which of the objects (dishes) should be shown. It works when, in a list, I have an anchor with an ui-sref containing the id like `ui-sref="app.dishdetails({id: dish._id})"` that fires when {{dish.image}} is clicked because the click comes in a certain dataset with an according index. What I need is probably an event and to feed the index into that event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your precious help JB Nizet and danday74! 
The problem was to let the template know the properties of which dish to show. The answers I found were in controllers.js. First, I had to correct an error, and then I created a $scope.property containing only the required dish:

```
var up = menuFactory.detDish(0);
$scope.up = up;
```

Then I could use {{up.image}}, {{up.name}} etc. in the template.

Answer (score 1):

don't use $stateParams

inject $state instead and then access

```
 $state.params.wotever
```